# how to edit waitForPageToLoadTime in RC

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-rc

I'm trying to open page using setup method

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome",
                                   "http://www.jobsite.co.uk/");
    selenium.start();
}

@Test
public void testCreateCustomer() throws Exception {
    ProjectSpecificScripts1 pss = new ProjectSpecificScripts1(this.selenium,
                                              this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    pss.sele = this.selenium;
    selenium.open("/");
}
```

But I'm getting an error:

> com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Timed out after 30000ms
>    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:97"

Sometimes the page will open but sometimes I'm getting a "Timed out after 30000ms" error. I'm not able to find where the setup method is defined, or how to edit `pageLoadTime`.

Comment: I assume you can connect to the site without any issues using a normal browser (i.e. it is not that the site itself is unreachable)?

Comment: Is there any other method instead of open()?  becuase implicit time is 30000ms i need to wait for 40000ms

Comment: I think you mean you want to use the [`setTimeout(40s)`](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#setTimeout(java.lang.String)) function?

Answer (score 0):

you can use method like this.

```
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("40000");
```